# Extract specific URL parts with regex and rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, formula, pcre

I'm trying to rewrite some urls and extract their parameter values via path names via one regular expression. The url can have multiple variations and s-term, pg-n, sort-order and so on can be in any order. Except for category which is always first after website url.

**Example 1:** www.test.com/freebies/s-term/pg-2/

- Extract $1=freebies , $2=term, $3=2
- So then i can rewrite to www.test.com?category=$1&s=$2&page=$3

**Example 2:**
www.test.com/freebies/pg-2/

- Extract $1=freebies , $2='', $3=2
- So then i can rewrite to www.test.com?category=$1&s=$2&page=$3

**All possible combinations**

```
http://localhost:8888/pg-2/
http://localhost:8888/s-term/
http://localhost:8888/s-term/pg-2/
http://localhost:8888/s-term/pg-2/
http://localhost:8888/freebies/
http://localhost:8888/freebies/pg-2/
http://localhost:8888/freebies/s-term/
http://localhost:8888/freebies/s-term/pg-2/
```

In either case i want to get category in group 1, searchterm in group 2, paging in group 3, sort-order in group 4

---

Here's what I tried so far, but in substitution area you can see it replaces each time it founds a match and i want to replace whole url with a new one and include the groups data.

https://regex101.com/r/4v1uf5/10

Do you think it's possible via regex or .htaccess rewrite would be a better plan?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is vague and cannot be answered in its current form. It is unclear how those variations are meant to be interpreted in a general pattern. You gave two examples, but from there no general pattern can be extruded. So either you need to provide many more (all?) possible combinations and their interpretation. Or, more helpful, you need to phrase such general pattern yourself.

Comment: is this what you're looking for `freebies\/(s-term|pg-2)\/{0,}(pg-\d){0,}`

Comment: @arkascha I tried to simplify the question as much as i could. So what i'm trying to achieve is to rewrite this url to use query parameters instead. First path is always category but the next ones are optional and in different orders. You can have an url taht shows category and apply a search term. Then you can have a category page wit h search term and paging applied. Or you can simply have a page with category and paging only. The main structure is this www.test.com/category/search/paging . I'll add more examples

Comment: @atoms Almost! The problem is that it places the group content in url path order but i want group 2 to always be search-term only. If it doesn't exist, then it's empty. And so on.

Comment: what about `freebies\/(s-term)\/{0,}(pg-\d){0,}|freebies\/pg-2\/(s-term){0,}`

Comment: It doesn't work for all multi-lines, dunno why. Also can you make it extract the term after "s-" and the paging number "2"? Those will be dynamic

Comment: @atoms Have a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/4v1uf5/11

Comment: it sounds like you should create a seperate rule for each desired pattern in your htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by using multiple groups one after another to extract the values:

```
(?:(freebies)\/|pg-([^\/]+)\/|s-([^\/]+)\/)\/?(?:s-([^\/]+)\/|pg-([^\/]+)\/)?(?:pg-([^\/]+)\/)?
```

Demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/4v1uf5/26